# SGD and quantile regression

Tags: gradient-descent, quantile-regression, stochastic-gradient-descent, vowpal-wabbit

It is [my understanding](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/287717/why-cant-the-gradient-descent-optimize-a-quantile-regression-loss) that the quantile loss is not differentiable (at 0) so base gradient descent cannot be used.

However, Vowpal Wabbit which is an SGD-based learner very much includes [quantile regression](https://github.com/VowpalWabbit/vowpal_wabbit/wiki/Loss-functions), and [calculates the derivative](https://github.com/VowpalWabbit/vowpal_wabbit/blob/fdaf8b1158958e10e8d65a63d6579f899d1df6c1/vowpalwabbit/loss_functions.cc#L311) as:

```
float e = label - prediction;
if(e == 0) return 0;
return e > 0 ? -tau : (1-tau);
```

Am I missing something here? Is this an accepted way to use SGD with QR?

Answer (score 1):

Many things in *applied* statistical computing (and computer science in general) is based on approximations. In case of absolute loss function, it has constant decrease rate for loss < 0 and constant increase rate at loss > 0, it neither increases, nor decreases at zero. That's about theory, but in practice, it is unlikely that you will hit exact zero. Moreover, it is not differentiable at zero, but since it is neither increasing, nor decreasing, 0 is a reasonable value to use if we need to choose something for our algorithm to work. If error is equal to zero, then we are done with training and not need to update the weights any more, so this makes perfect sense.

Comment: So we basically ignore the mathematical properties of the function and say that this is a "good enough" approximation?

Comment: @Bar can you point *any* harm in setting the derivative to zero in here? It is zero when error is zero. If error is zero, then we are done with training and not need to update the weights any more, so this makes perfect sense.

Comment: I don't see any harm practically, but the derivarive is undefined for 0 mathematically. I guess we can justify it as selecting a value from the subderivatives.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Gradient Descent in quantile-regression. I experimented with some toy data (both 1D and 4D) and this works fine and gives similar results to the linear programming methods (simplex, interior-point) and to the IRLS method.

The objective in (simple=1D) quantile regression is:

$$ \mathcal L= \sum_i \rho_\alpha(y_i-\beta_0-x\cdot\beta_1)$$

where $\rho_\alpha(y_i-\beta_0-x\cdot\beta_1)= \begin{cases} (\alpha-1)(y_i-\beta_0-x\cdot\beta_1), &y_i-\beta_0-x\cdot\beta_1<0 \\ \alpha(y_i-\beta_0-x\cdot\beta_1), & y_i-\beta_0-x\cdot\beta_1 \ge 0
\end{cases}
$

If we take the gradient w.r.t. say $\beta_0$, you get $1-\alpha$ in the 1st case, and $-\alpha$ in the 2nd case. You can evaluate the conditions given some initial $\beta$'s, and then sum on the data, and so you can perform gradient-descent.

Here is how I defined the `quant_loss` in python (`tau` replacing $\alpha$):

```
def quant_loss(y_hat, y):
    e = y - y_hat
    loss = (tau-1)*e*(e<0) + tau*e*(e>=0)
    return loss.sum()
```

You can check out my code implementation in Python on GitHub [here](https://gist.github.com/MaverickMeerkat/7e1a96f0e87c9b444a7fa146fbb6b2dd).